# Using a tag as submit button

Tags: html, css, forms

How can I use a tag as submit button in my form (Is just matter of design for me and not functionality)

`My form`

```
<form action="{{route('wishlist.store')}}" method="post">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <input type="text" name="user_id" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}" hidden>
  <input type="text" name="product_id" value="{{$product->id}}" hidden>


  <button type="submit" class="wish-list">
    <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
  </button>
</form>
```

[image: screen one]

All the issue I have is that gray box behind my font icon which is caused by `<button>` so I need to use `<a>` tag.

I also tried to change my button with a tag and added something like:

```
$(document).on("click","#sendwish",function(){
    $('form').submit(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        var url = $('form').attr("action");
        var formData = $('form').serialize();
        $.post(url, formData, function(response){
            console.log(response);
        });
    });
});
```

but it didn't work.

any idea?

Comment: Why not just remove the default styles from the button?

```
.wish-list {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can just overwrite default styles on the button?

```
.wish-list {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

or if need be:

`<button style="background: none; border: none; padding: 0; margin: 0;"></button>`

Comment: Example solution with bootstrap 4 and font-awesome: https://jsfiddle.net/cuzghgw1/

Answer (score 0):

Give your a form an ID as well as the link and call the onclick function to then submit the form.

Let's say you have a form called with an ID of SubmitMe and a span / div with the ID of ClickMe.

Example:

```
document.getElementById("#ClickMe").onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById("#SubmitMe").submit();
}
```

Just so you know this, this will submit what ever is the action on the "SubmitMe" form.